# How to process multi column dictionary grouping results

Tags: c#, dictionary, grouping

I am sorry if this a duplicate question. If it is duplicate please let me know where I can find it.

I find it hard for me to understand the concept of Grouping especially how to process the grouping results. Can anybody explain me how to process the results of multi column dictionary grouping.

I have dictionary of type

```
Dictionary<string, AsynchRunItem2> AsynchRunItems.
```

string is key that we are generating using 4 other properties.

AsynchRunItem2 has following properties:

```
string UniverseIDs;

DateTime StartDate;

DateTime EndDate;
```

In AsynchRunItems, I get four records. Please see below for Values. I left Keys.

`UniverseIDs:15       StartDate:10/9/2013  EndDate : 10/31/2013`

`UniverseIDs:20       StartDate:10/9/2013  EndDate : 10/31/2013`

`UniverseIDs:50,55    StartDate:09/30/2013 EndDate : 10/31/2013`

`UniverseIDs:60,64    StartDate:09/30/2013 EndDate : 10/31/2013`

I want to group AsynchRunItems on StartDate and EndDate so that I can get like below using Lambda not LINQ please.

`UniverseIDs:15,20          StartDate:10/9/2013  EndDate : 10/31/2013`

`UniverseIDs:50,55,60,64    StartDate:09/30/2013 EndDate : 10/31/2013`

I am grouping like below but want to know how I can process grouping results

```
var temp = AsynchRunItems.GroupBy(g => new { g.Value.StartDate,g.Value.EndDate});
```

I want to know how to move forward and work on temp so that I can get what I want.

Comment: Do you need the `string` key value with the `AsyncRunItems` going forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroupBy returns a collection of IGrouping objects, where each IGrouping object has a Key property and also is itself a collection--a collection of the items from the original collection (AsynchRunItems).  So you can see the return of GropyBy as a collection of collections, and you can do stuff like loop through the collection of IGrouping objects, or loop through the items grouped within particular IGrouping objects.  Or you could use Enumerable extension functions to operate on either of those.

Perhaps you are getting confused by the fact that the original collection is a Dictionary.  Because a Dictionary is a collection of KevValuePair objects, each IGrouping object returned by your GroupBy method is a collection of the same type of KeyValuePair objects.  It might be easier to understand if you did this:

```
            var groupedAsynchRunItems 
                = AsynchRunItems.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                    .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
```

This returns a collection where each IGrouping has been converted to a Dictionary.  By doing this, you would lose the Key property of the IGrouping objects.  Really, the only reason you should do this is if you need to use the functionality of members of the Dictionary class.  I'm only suggesting it as a way to learn how an IGrouping works.  We could even go one better here:

```
var groupedAsynchRunItems
            = AsynchRunItems.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
```

That gives you a Dictionary of Dictionaries, which might help show how the return value of the GroupBy method is already kind of like a Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. I got more idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the results as you have them grouped (which is certainly doable with your current `GroupBy()` method), just do something like this:

```
foreach(var t in temp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("UniverseIDs: {0} StartDate:{1} EndDate: {2}", string.Join(", ", t.ToList().Select (x => x.Value.UniverseIDs).ToArray()), t.Key.StartDate, t.Key.EndDate);
}
```

That gives me this output when I quickly attempted to duplicate your sample values:

> UniverseIDs: 15, 20 StartDate:10/9/2013 EndDate:
>   10/31/2013 
>   UniverseIDs: 50, 55, 60, 64 StartDate:9/30/2013
>   EndDate: 10/31/2013

If you are confused by what is contained in your temp variable, please see Tony's answer.